# How to covert image into string of binary?

Tags: python, image-processing, binary, decode, encode

How would you take an image file as an input and output it as a string of binary? Preferably in python.

Comment: what did you try ? show yor code.

Comment: You can use the built in bytearray method but I can't help much if I don't know what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @finlay what type of image do you want to convert? Is it a color image(RGB format), Gray-scale image or Binary Image?

Comment: No need to write any code, just in Terminal `xxd -b -g0 image.jpg`